# Java Heap Space doesn't increase when setting Xms Xmx ,

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I deployed an application in tomcat. I need to increase java heap size to avoid java heap space error.

I added setenv.sh and setenv.bat in bin dir of tomcat with this content:
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms8192M -Xmx8192M -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

But when I monitor by jconsole, Max heap size is set to 3GB. Why setenv doesn't take effect on heap size?
How can I increase java heap space?

Comment: I sometimes ran into issues when I got typos on such settings; and then maybe you dont notice because no layer will log that. So - did you try to invoke that java that your tomcat is using with exactly those parameters directly? Just to make sure that there isnt any typo? And of course: you did restart Tomcat before looking into jconsole?

Comment: in a terminal, check with `ps uxww` if these arguments are passed to the java process.

Answer (score -1):

I Think the problem that your JVM is 32-bit, Using 64-bit JVM will fix the issue.

Comment: That’s very unlikely. The common implementations (say Oracle or OpenJDK) immediately bail out, if the specified max size is unsupported. Further, they don’t even support 3GB heap in their 32Bit version.

Comment: the JVM is 64-bit.